# What would cause this error pam_setcred(): Permission denied

Tags: ssh, pam, duosecurity

Server is joined to AD realm and allows groups SSH access. I am in one group and 2 users are in another group. SSH works for me and one of the two users. The user that fails to login via ssh has this in /var/log/secure
Thank you for looking.

````
Jan 11 12:53:34 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: starting Duo Unix: PAM Duo
Jan 11 12:53:34 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: pam_duo(sshd:auth): conversation failed
Jan 11 12:53:34 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: Aborted Duo login for 'anl14042admin' from 137.99.80.134: Error gathering user response
Jan 11 12:53:34 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: starting Duo Unix: PAM Duo
Jan 11 12:53:35 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: pam_duo(sshd:auth): conversation failed
Jan 11 12:53:35 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: Aborted Duo login for 'anl14042admin' from 137.99.80.134: Error gathering user response
Jan 11 12:53:37 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: Failed password for anl14042admin from 137.99.80.134 port 50494 ssh2


pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=137.99.80.134 user=anl14042admin
Jan 11 12:53:47 StorrsOOD sshd[2789700]: starting Duo Unix: PAM Duo
Jan 11 12:53:48 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: Postponed keyboard-interactive/pam for anl14042admin from 137.99.80.134 port 50494 ssh2 [preauth]
Jan 11 12:53:55 StorrsOOD sshd[2789700]: Successful Duo login for 'anl14042admin' from 137.99.80.134
Jan 11 12:53:55 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: Postponed keyboard-interactive/pam for anl14042admin from 137.99.80.134 port 50494 ssh2 [preauth]
Jan 11 12:53:55 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for anl14042admin from 137.99.80.134 port 50494 ssh2
Jan 11 12:53:55 StorrsOOD sshd[2789625]: fatal: PAM: pam_setcred(): Permission denied```

[root@StorrsOOD alf02013admin]# realm list
grove.ad.uconn.edu
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: GROVE.AD.UCONN.EDU
  domain-name: grove.ad.uconn.edu
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-tools
  login-formats: %U
  login-policy: allow-permitted-logins
  permitted-logins: 
  permitted-groups: ms.UITS.server.admins, ms.ITS.StorrsOOD.admins
````